# converting rdd list of list unicode values into string

Tags: python-2.7, pyspark, rdd, python-unicode

I've a spark rdd which has values in unicode as list of list :

```
ex_rdd.take(5)
[[u'70450535982412348', u'1000000923', u'1'],
 [u'535982417348', u'1000000923', u'1'],
 [u'50535929459899', u'1000000923', u'99'],
 [u'8070450535936297811', u'1000000923', u'1'],
 [u'5937908667', u'1000000923', u'1']]
```

To write them into a hdfs file ,it is giving a `unicode error`.How do i convert them to string and write them in file efficiently in pyspark? hdfs output file should look like below -

```
 70450535982412348,1000000923,1
 535982417348,1000000923,1
```

and so on

Comment: you can try encoding them? ex_rdd.map(lambda x:[y.encode('utf-8') for y in x])

Comment: yeah this can be done but since file is huge encoding all the values is really not efficient

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Python's `join` function for strings, along with the `map` and `saveAsTextFile` operations on pyspark.RDD objects (see the documentation [here](http://spark.apache.org/docs/2.2.0/api/python/pyspark.html#pyspark.RDD)).

```py
ex_rdd.map(lambda L: ','.join(L)).saveAsTextFile('/path/to/hdfs/save/file')
```

This should be available on even the earlier versions (>= 1.0) of PySpark, if I'm not mistaken.

I'm not sure what you mean by "`unicode error`". Is this an exception in Python? Or is this an exception in the Java internals?